# Retrieve levels of a nested json

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Any techniques to know the number of levels that a nested JSON would contain?

For eg:

```
animals = [
    {
        "animal" : {
            "type" : "bunny"
        }
    },
    {
        "animal" : {}
    },
    {}
]
```

Comment: Probably a recursive approach.  There are plenty of SO answers that cover how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple recursive function:

```
def get_depth(d):  
  c = [1 if not isinstance(b, dict) else 1+get_depth(b) for a, b in d.items()]
  return max(c) if c else 0

animals = [{'animal': {'type': 'bunny'}}, {'animal': {}}, {}]
print(max(map(get_depth, animals)))
```

Output:

```
2
```